# how to replace style in tag html table with JavaScript for export to CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I try to replace all tags in the HTML table but when I try,  it can't replace them because it has a `style` attribute in the `<span>` tag. Here is my HTML and JavaScript code.

```js
function doCsv(){
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML;
  var data = table.replace(/<thead>/g, '')
  .replace(/<\/thead>/g, '')
  .replace(/<tbody>/g, '')
  .replace(/<\/tbody>/g, '')
  .replace(/<tr>/g, '')
  .replace(/<\/tr>/g, '\r\n')
  .replace(/<th>/g, '')
  .replace(/<\/th>/g, ',')
  .replace(/<td>/g, '')
  .replace(/<\/td>/g, ',')
  .replace(/<span>/g, '', '""')
  .replace(/<\/span>/g, '', '""');
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" id="myTable" style="text-align: left;">
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2016-11-21 09:45:32</td>
    <td>test test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>2016-11-21 - 2016-11-21 (1)</td>
    <td><span style="color:green">test</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.innerText`  instead of `innerHTML` to return just the text contents.

You can also use `querySelectorAll("<any css code>")` to narrow down your search.

In the example below, I have used two CSS tags: `tr>th` and `tr>td`  which basically means

"any TH element that is a descendant of a TR element"

and

"any TD element that is a descendant of a TR element"

Combined with `querySelectorAll()` which returns an array of elements that I can then access using simple array methods like for loops

**UPDATE**

I updated the example so that it would generate a proper CSV file (more or less) by adding a nested `querySelectorAll()` function call to each `TR` element.

```js
function doCsv() {
  var _data = "";
  var table = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    // each TR is stored in table[i]
    var entry = table[i];

    // all TD and TH elements for that TR are stored in entry_children
    var entry_children = entry.querySelectorAll("td,th");

    for (var u = 0; u < entry_children.length; u++) {
      _data += entry_children[u].innerText + ",";
    }

    // add return at end of last child TR/TH element
    _data += "\r\n";


  }

  alert(_data);
}
doCsv();
```

```html
<table width="100%" id="myTable" style="text-align: left;">
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2016-11-21 09:45:32</td>
    <td>test test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>2016-11-21 - 2016-11-21 (1)</td>
    <td><span style="color:green">test</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: why it show undefined when i export to csv file and not in  table  pattern ?

Comment: Because  data was not defined  -- I updated answer with `var data = ""`

Comment: i try you code but it still not work for me pattern when export to csv not like table and still show undefined sorry i just newbie for this

Comment: Click on run under my answer to generate a valid CSV (except for the very last comma)